# Using Sklearn Log loss and accuracy_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to import the following library and have scikit-learn installed into my system:

```
from sklearn.metrics.classification import accuracy_score, log_loss
```

Can someone please tell what the issue is.
I am seeing the following error:

```
No module named 'sklearn.metrics.classification
```

Comment: Both `accuracy_score` and `log_loss` are in `sklearn.metrics` module (and as per error, `sklearn` does not have `metrics.classification` module)

Answer (score 1):

Latest versions of `scikit-learn` requires you to import this metrics directly from `metrics`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, log_loss
```